# Why is my browser displaying the Content-Type line?

Tags: apache2, cgi, browser

Following what's described here --- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html --- I've created a tiny Perl document:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";
print "Hello, World.";
```

and called it `first.pl`. I've also modified it so that it looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
print "Hello, World.";
```

because a friend pointed out that the meaning of "\n" is system-dependent, and what's required is CR-LF CR-LF, but the results are the same.)

When I look at `localhost/~mylogin/first.pl` from the Chrome browser I get the following output:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Hello, World.
```

(The `; charset=...` stuff is a slight modification of what the Apache docs suggest, because leaving it off also produced a Content-Type line of output, and some searching suggested that the charset thing might be important. As it happened, it made no difference.)

The references Apache docs say "wherever you put your file, you will see the **one line** `Hello, World.` appear in your browser window. "

Clearly, I'm seeing **two** lines, the first of which should have been merely treated as description of the remaining content, and I think that's a problem.

I'm hoping that this is some really basic mistake, and would appreciate any suggestions.

**Context**

I'm on a Mac running Monterey 12.6.6

I got started following instructions from [here](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250004361).

Starting from the vanilla `httpd.conf` file, I've made just a few edits, uncommenting
the following:

```
LoadModule perl_module libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

And in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`, I've uncommented

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
```

I've created `/etc/apache2/users/mylogin.conf`, and given it this content:

```
<Directory "/Users/mylogin/Sites/"> 
  AddLanguage en .en 
  AddHandler perl-script .pl 
  PerlHandler ModPerl::Registry 
  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI 
  AllowOverride None 
  Require host localhost
</Directory>
```

I've run

```
chmod +a "_www allow execute" ~
```

[in all cases above, I've replaced "mylogin" with my actual login, of course]

And then, following instructions from Apache, I added this to the `httpd.conf` file:

```
<Directory "/Users/mylogin/Sites">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi 
</Directory>
```

Comment: Does it work fine when you **un**modify the line you changed?

Comment: Alas, no. Even using the apache-suggested `Content-type` rather than `Content-Type` (which is what the spec seems to require) and getting rid of `; charset=utf-8` doesn't seem to work, whether using `\n\n` or `\r\n\r\n`, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `AddHandler perl-script .pl`, you do not run the script with [`mod_cgid`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cgid.html) (or [`mod_cgi`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cgi.html)) which the "[Apache Tutorial: Dynamic Content with CGI](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html)" is about, but with [`mod_perl`](https://perl.apache.org/). While both can run Perl scripts, it is the CGI that expects the script to first send headers separated by `\n\n` from the body.

You can see the difference by switching between these configurations:

#### mod_perl

```
LoadModule perl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_perl.so

<Directory "/Users/mylogin/Sites/">
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler perl-script .pl
  PerlHandler ModPerl::Registry
</Directory>
```

Produces:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache/2.4.41
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/x-perl
< 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Hello, World.
```

#### mod_cgid

```
LoadModule cgid_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cgid.so

<Directory "/Users/mylogin/Sites/">
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .pl
</Directory>
```

Produces:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache/2.4.41
< Content-Length: 13
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< 
Hello, World.
```

Comment: Bless you! This (more or less) did the trick. I had to change your `LoadModule` to a different directory: `LoadModule cgid_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgid.so`, which I guessed from looking at the default `httpd.conf` file. And I had to add `Require host localhost` to make it work as well, which worries me a little when it comes to trying to reach this outside localhost...but that's a different problem for another day.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Esa Jokinen's answer, I got things working, in the sense that loading `http://localhost/~jfh/first.pl` produced the expected one-line result, but I thought it'd be worth recording the final configuration state, because it required some slight fiddling.

To review:
I got started following instructions from [here](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250004361).

Starting from the vanilla `httpd.conf` file, I've made just a few edits, uncommenting
the following:

```
LoadModule perl_module libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

And in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`, I've uncommented

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
```

I've created `/etc/apache2/users/jfh.conf`, and given it this content:

```
LoadModule cgid_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgid.so

<Directory "/Users/jfh/Sites/">
  AddLanguage en .en
  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
  Options +ExecCGI
  AllowOverride None
  Require host localhost
  AddHandler cgi-script .pl
</Directory>
```

I've run

```
chmod +a "_www allow execute" ~
```

[in all cases above, my login is `jfh`, and if you want to copy this, you'll need to change that to your own login]

I did *not* make further edits to the `httpd.conf` file as described in my original question, but instead made the edits shown above in `/etc/apache2/users/jfh.conf`.

I hope this helps out someone else with comparable problems on a comparable system.

Finally, a concern I had about the difference between `\r\n` and `\n` in various perl versions seems to have been misplaced, for my `first.pl` file looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "Hello, World.";
```

and works fine (but I've also confirmed that it works fine when the `\n\n` is replaced with `\r\n\r\n`).